# Is it possible to redirect a url using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm working on a project using spring, MVC, and implementing webapp-runner. The project used to have a hierarchy like /test/home/index.jsp but using webapp-runner it changed to /home/index.jsp. So, What I need is to support and redirect the old url's with "/test/home/index.jsp" to "/home/index.jsp" so the page doesn't brake in case an old url is used.
I will be thankful if anyone can give me a hand.

Answer (score 2):

```
 return "redirect:/home/index.jsp";
```

in your controller that returns viewname, or create a second controller with the required mapping .

Comment: so, is there any way to catch up all urls and redirect using a main controller?

Comment: tuckey url rewrite, but spring controllers take expressions not just hard coded strings

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by having an Apache2 in the web app server redirecting the old traffic to the new URL structure.

Installing it in the server is as simple as running

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Whether I'd use rewrite or redirect would depend wether you want to maintain the old URLs or not.
See here for more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if that can be configured since I'm deploying to heroku.